# Duplicating model

Tags: modeling, objects

I have no clue as to what I'm doing, but I'm trying to help my son with a new 3d rigged model he purchased. He wants to load a copy of the same blender model into the same window with the original one. His goal is to create a fight scene between the duplicate models. My son has tried to load the model again, but it opens a new window. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The quick answer is Shift D to duplicate or Alt D to create an instance.  You probably want the latter, don't have time to write a full answer just now.

Comment: Thank you, but it makes a duplicate over the original model and we can't move the entire duplicate, it only moves parts.